# How to upgrade nopcommerce 1.8 to 3.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nopcommerce

I am newbie in nopcommerce, and want to  upgrade my old version 1.8 to version 3.5. My old 1.8 version site is up running and have got lots of data in it including products/ customers and orders.

any suggestion would be helpful about the best way to do upgrade process please.

Many thanks in advance.

Prabir

Comment: I believe that if you worked only with theme and plugins ( no source code changes of original NC source code), you should upgrade your plugins and adjust your theme into 3.5 version, then execute each sql upgrade scripts for 1.8. to 1.9 till 3.5